# Authentication: suppressing the creds confirmation when credentials are passed in an HTTP URL

Tags: url, authentication

I am trying to write a script that will provide XML data to a third party client. I wish to require that all clients are authenticated in order to make use of the system.

Rather than using a bespoke authentication system, which would be overkill, I want client applications to just pass in their credentials via the url, such as `http://myusername:mypassword@mysite.com/`.  This is not unlike how it is done in FTP.

I think this is possible using .htaccess, but when I do try it, I still get a dialog prompt asking me to login or confirm the credentials that I will be using to login. Is there a way that I can suppress this in the .htaccess or an alternative way of authenticating on the server?

Comment: It'll work in most browsers, but issue all kinds of warnings. This construct was massively abused by phishers/spammers to create `http://www.microsoft.com@somenastysite.com` type urls. The warnings cannot be disabled without compromising security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a security fix of the Internet Explorer, which was introduced by Microsoft some years ago. If you retry it with Firefox, it should work.

If you want to allow the Internet Explorer to login via the given username and password, check out [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489) on the theme, especially the workaround section. And btw, the url is supposed to be http://username:password@example.com (note the double-slash).

Also, please make sure your .htaccess is correct by entering your login-information in the credentials popup - you should be able to login anyways.